# How can I refactor my scss code from import to use rule? It's not working to me

Tags: css, sass, styles, scss-mixins

I'm doing refactor of my CSS files from @import to @use.

_foo.scss

```
@mixin loadFontFace($fontFamily, $fontName, $fontLocal: '', $fontLocalAlt: '', $fontWeight: 400, $fontStyle: normal, $font-variation: normal) {
  @font-face {
    font-weight: $fontWeight;
    font-family: $fontFamily;
    font-style: $fontStyle;
    unicode-range: 'U+0-1FFFFF';

    @if ($fontLocal != '' and $fontLocalAlt != '') {
      src: local($fontLocal),
      local($fontLocalAlt),
      asset-url('#{$fontName}.woff2') format('woff2-variations'),
      asset-url('#{$fontName}.ttf') format('truetype-variations');
    } @else {
      src: asset-url('#{$fontName}.woff2') format('woff2-variations'),
      asset-url('#{$fontName}.ttf') format('truetype-variations');
    }
  }
}
```

_main.scss

```
@use "foo" as *;

@include loadFontFace($fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',$fontName: 'ubuntu-variable',$fontWeight: 1 999,$fontStyle: normal);
```

I've got a message: no mixin named loadFontFace

When I change the namespace from "*" to "as foo", I got a message:
Invalid CSS after "@include foo": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ".loadFontFace($font"

My sass version is "1.45.2".

Do you know where is the problem, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> When I change the namespace from "*" to "as foo", I got a message:
> Invalid CSS after "@include foo": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was
> ".loadFontFace($font"

If you import a module without the alias, it will namespace it e.g. if your module is called `_foo.scss`, you can include and use it like that:

```
@use 'foo'; // everything inside foo will be namespaced with 'foo'

@include foo.loadFontFace(...) // foo prefix
```

When you use an alias, you can rename this 'foo' prefix. `as *` means, that everything inside foo will be included without a namespace prefix.

```
@use 'foo' as *; // everything inside foo will be available just like the old @import

@include loadFontFace(...) // no prefix
```

> Do you know where is the problem, please?

Your code looks okay. It must be related to the path of the include. Just make sure that you put the correct path for foo -> either an absolute path or a relative path:

```
@use 'foo' // foo is in the same folder as main
@use 'mixin/foo' // foo is in the subfolder mixin
@use '../mixin/foo' // foo is in the folder mixin relative to main's parent folder
@use 'src/styles/mixin/foo' // import from absolute path
// ... etc
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to make the link to `_foo.scss` more specific.

If `_foo.scss` is in the same directory, instead write:

```
@use "./foo" as *;
```

This should link up correctly.

Comment: This is not an issue. It can resolve files from the same directory without the `./`.